# Using Opal API with C++

Tags: c++, sockets, voip, opalvoip

I'm trying to make a VoIP program using SIP and OPAL, but I'm currently stuck with opal because I simply can't figure out how to use it. I have read documentation many many many times but no luck at all. Currently I think that `OpalConnection:OpalConnection(/*arg*/)` should do the connection job, i mean just to connect but on the other end I have a `OpalListener`,

`OpalListener:Open()` and `OpalListener:Accept()` but they don't do the job like good old `accept()` from socket.h. So if anyone can explain to me sequence of calling the OPAL API functions it would be very much appreciated.

On the other hand I'm considering of trying my luck with reSIProcate, but just like in opal it would be nice to know the basic sequence but no luck finding anything.